# Scrapy scrapes from only some pages -- Crawled(200) (referer: None) Error?

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy, web-crawler

I have written a scrapy project to scrape some data from the Congress.gov website. Originally, I was hoping to scrape the data on all bills. My code ran, and downloaded the data I wanted but only for about 1/2 the bills. So I began troubleshooting. I turned on the autothrottle in the settings, and included middleware code for too many requests. I then limited the search criteria to just a particular congress (97th) for just bills originating in the Senate, and re-ran the code. It downloaded most of the bills, but again some were missing. I then tried to scrape just the pages that were missing. In particular, I tried scraping page 32 I was able to scrape successfully. So why won't it scrape all the pages when I use the recursive code?

Can anyone help me to figure out what the problem is? Here is the code I used to scrape the info from all bills in the 97th congress:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from senatescraper.items import senatescraperSampleItem
from scrapy.http.request import Request

class SenatebotSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = 'recursivesenatetablebot2'
    allowed_domains = ['www.congress.gov']

    def start_requests(self):
        baseurl = "https://www.congress.gov/search?q=%7B%22source%22%3A%22legislation%22%2C%22chamber%22%3A%22Senate%22%2C%22congress%22%3A%5B%2297%22%5D%2C%22type%22%3A%5B%22bills%22%5D%7D&page="
        for i in xrange(1,32):
            beginurl= baseurl + `i`
            yield Request(beginurl, self.parse_bills)

    def parse_bills(self, response):
        sel= Selector(response)
        bills=sel.xpath("//span[5][@class='result-item']")
        for bill in bills:
            bill_url=bill.css("span.result-item a::attr(href)").extract()[0]
            yield Request(url=bill_url, callback=self.parse_items)

    def parse_items(self, response):
        sel=Selector(response)
        rows=sel.css('table.item_table tbody tr')
        items=[]    
        for row in rows:
            item = senatescraperSampleItem()
            item['bill']=response.css('h1.legDetail::text').extract()
            item['dates']=row.xpath('./td[1]/text()').extract()[0]
            item['actions']=row.css('td.actions::text').extract()
            item['congress']=response.css('h2.primary::text').extract()
            items.append(item)
        return items
```

This is the code I used to just scrape page 32 of search with filters for the 97th congress, bills originating in the senate only:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from startingover.items import startingoverSampleItem


class DebuggingSpider(BaseSpider):
name = 'debugging'
allowed_domains = ['www.congress.gov']

def start_requests(self):
    yield scrapy.Request('https://www.congress.gov/search?q=%7B%22source%22%3A%22legislation%22%2C%22chamber%22%3A%22Senate%22%2C%22congress%22%3A%5B%2297%22%5D%2C%22type%22%3A%5B%22bills%22%5D%7D&page=32', self.parse_page)

def parse_page(self, response):
    sel= Selector(response)
    bills=sel.xpath("//span[5][@class='result-item']")
    for bill in bills:
        bill_url=bill.css("span.result-item a::attr(href)").extract()[0]
        yield Request(url=bill_url, callback=self.parse_items)

def parse_items(self, response):
    sel=Selector(response)
    rows=sel.css('table.item_table tbody tr')
    items=[]    
    for row in rows:
        item = startingoverSampleItem()
        item['bill']=response.css('h1.legDetail::text').extract()
        item['dates']=row.xpath('./td[1]/text()').extract()[0]
        item['actions']=row.css('td.actions::text').extract()
        item['congress']=response.css('h2.primary::text').extract()
        items.append(item)
    return items
```

And my item:

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
class senatescraperSampleItem(Item):
    bill=Field()
    actions=Field(serializer=str)
    congress=Field(serializer=str)
    dates=Field()
```

Comment: The `for i in xrange(1,32):` is incorrectly indented on your question.

Comment: fixed that. Also updated the question -- I was able to get page 32, which wouldn't scrape using the recursive code, to scrape individually. But why is my recursive code scraping sporadically?

Comment: Are you getting the following error when you start the crawl: `ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: /bill/97th-congress/house-bill/5118`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't see half of the things you are trying to scrap because you are not taking care of resolving relative urls. Using `response.urljoin` should remedy the situation.

```
yield Request(url=response.urljoin(bill_url), callback=self.parse_items)
```

You may experience this exception:

```
2018-01-30 17:27:13 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://www.congress.gov/search?q=%7B%22source%22%3A%22legislation%22%2C%22chamber%22%3A%2
2Senate%22%2C%22congress%22%3A%5B%2297%22%5D%2C%22type%22%3A%5B%22bills%22%5D%7D&page=5> (referer: None)                                                               
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jorge/.virtualenvs/scrapy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 102, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
  File "/home/jorge/.virtualenvs/scrapy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/offsite.py", line 30, in process_spider_output
    for x in result:
  File "/home/jorge/.virtualenvs/scrapy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/referer.py", line 339, in <genexpr>
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "/home/jorge/.virtualenvs/scrapy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/urllength.py", line 37, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "/home/jorge/.virtualenvs/scrapy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/depth.py", line 58, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "/tmp/stackoverflow/senatescraper/senatescraper/spiders/senatespider.py", line 25, in parse_bills
    bill_url = bill.css("span.result-item a::attr(href)").extract()[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

To ensure you are getting the URL from the element with text "All actions" and don't caught anything weird that may exists before that element you should combine your xpath query as follows:

```
def parse_bills(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        bills = sel.xpath(
            '//a[contains(@href, "all-actions")]/@href').extract()
        for bill in bills:
            yield Request(
                url=response.urljoin(bill),
                callback=self.parse_items,
                dont_filter=True)
```

Note the `dont_filter=True` argument, I added it as scrapy was filtering links I already crawled (this is the default configuration). You can removed it if you manage the filtering of duplicate links in a different manner.

When you get exceptions, you can always wrap them around `try` and `except` and start [the debugging shell of scrapy](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html#invoking-the-shell-from-spiders-to-inspect-responses) in the `except` block, it will help you inspect the response and see what's going on.

Comment: Ok. I will give that a try and report back.

Comment: Indeed, I am now getting lots of these errors: IndexError: list index out of range
2018-01-30 19:30:11 [scrapy.extensions.throttle] INFO: slot: www.congress.gov | conc: 1 | delay:  759 ms (+98) | latency:  759 ms | size: 64790 bytes
2018-01-30 19:30:11 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.congress.gov/search?q=%7B%22source%22%3A%22legislation%22%2C%22chamber%22%3A%22Senate%22%2C%22congress%22%3A%5B%2297%22%5D%2C%22type%22%3A%5B%22bills%22%5D%7D&page=13> (referer: None)

Comment: There must be something missing on some of those pages, if I were you I would start by reviewing the HTML of those pages to look what you are missing

Comment: That's what I thought too. I did check them. But I can't spot anything different, and I can download those pages one by one using the second program above.

Comment: Seems that there is one more link besides the link on "All Action", in page 5 you one of these. Tell me if the pages were the exception happens have this in common.

Comment: what the code for the other link? I'm not seeing it.

Comment: oh! I see it has an H.R. ref link -- a link to the corresponding house legislation. That might be it. So then how do I get just the all actions link?

Comment: That's it! That's got to be it. So how do I get just the all actions link?

Comment: I'm trying this:

    bill_url=bill.xpath('//a[contains(@href, "all-actions")]')

Comment: If it works and solves the issue completely, please accept my answer :)

Comment: Unfortunately, this seems to have made my problem much worse. The code runs, but now only produces about 100 results. So something is still very wrong. Trying to figure it out still.

Answer (score 0):

I made the following change to my code and it worked perfectly:

```
def parse_bills(self, response):
        bills=Selector(response)
        billlinks=bills.xpath('//a[contains(@href,"/all-actions")]/@href')
        for link in billlinks:
            urllink=link.extract()
            yield Request(url=urllink, callback=self.parse_items)
```